# Multipass rendering with framebuffer texture in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer

In OpenGL ES, I am drawing to a framebuffer-texture object. Is there a way to multipass draw on the same texture, using the textures own data from the previous draw? You would have to clear the texture after the first draw, but then it seems that the data would be erased which is required for the second. Would I have to create two separate textures? And bind the second texture to the framebuffer? I hate to have to use that VRAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, under most circumstances, you can't use the same texture as a render target and for texturing at the same time. This is what the spec calls a "rendering feedback loop", which produces undefined results. From section 4.4.4 of the ES 2.0 spec:

> A feedback loop may exist when a texture object is used as both the source and destination of a GL operation. When a feedback loop exists, undeﬁned behavior results.

There are some exceptions where the results are defined, particularly if the same mipmap levels are not used for both the render target and for texturing. But that's a somewhat esoteric case (e.g. it can be used if you want to implement your own mipmap generation). It does not help you do what you intend.

So for multipass rendering of the kind you have in mind, you need two textures, where one is used as source and the other one as the destination. Note that even if you need more than two passes, you typically still only need two textures. You can "ping pong" between the two in each pass, so that the destination from pass `n` becomes the source in pass `n + 1`, and the source from pass `n` becomes the destination in pass `n + 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, but so be it.